# How to get HP BiosConfigUtility.exe?

Tags: windows-7, bios

I need to manage my BIOS accounts on an HP EliteBook 8530p and I found [this guide](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03767649). Unfortunately, I'm stuck at the beginning:

> Download and install latest HP System Software Manager for notebook
>
> NOTE: Try always to download the latest Version.

So I did, from [here](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_SSM.html). Then, they started talking about a directory, which does not exist in my computer (I don't have HP SoftPaq Download Manager installed):

> In Command Prompt navigate to C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP SoftPaq Download Manager

That's where `BiosConfigUtility.exe` should be located. Do you have any experience with this?

I just want to have `BiosConfigUtility.exe` (haven't found a download) and be able to run it, why all this pain?

Comment: This is practically a textbook example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730). Instead of asking where to find the tool you think you need, it would be better to ask how to accomplish the task you're seeking to perform. For example, if you need to change some particular system setting, ask how to change that setting, not where to find the tool to change the setting. See the linked question on [meta.se] for more details on this question anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now, but may help someone else searching for this, below is the current direct download link for the BCU.

http://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_BCU.html